# What is the notion behind 'Pinned GC handle'?

Tags: .net, wpf, garbage-collection

When we analyse memory heaps, following 4 types of GC handles we generally come across:

1. Weak:- A weak GC handle will not prevent the instance it corresponds to from being garbage collected. `Example, used by the System.WeakReference class instances`.
2. Normal:- A normal GC handle prevents the corresponding instance from being garbage collected.`Example, used by the instances of strong references`.
3. RefCounted:- A reference counted GC handle is used internally by the runtime, `example, when dealing with COM interfaces.`
4. Pinned:- ***Why do we need this kind of GC handle? Is it just for avoiding the movement of that instance in memory or `is there any other notion behind this? I want to know the notion behind Pinned GC handle(with an example).`***

**Edited for Itay's answer**:- I have a non empty array-***DiffCell[][]*** which is bound to a data grid in WPF. When I close the window on which this data grid is present, on heap I see *Pinned GC handle* pointing to this empty ***DiffCell*** array through ***object[]***(see snapshot). `I am not using any unsafe code. I am just setting ItemsSource of data grid to null before closing that window. So my question is who does pin this array on heap and why?`

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need this in case we use pointers.
Imagine that you declare a pointer to a memory location and you do not pin in.
The GC sometimes move memory chunks to other places so your pointer will get invalid.

for example:

```
public unsafe void DoSomething(byte b)
{
   byte * bp = &b;
}
```

this will not compile because you didn't fix memory location that holds the byte.
In order to pin it you can use:

```
public unsafe void DoSomething(byte b)
{
   fixed(byte * bp = &b)
   {
        //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Itay! Please see edited question and let me know your comments on it.

Comment: I don't really know how WPF and binding work so I am afraid that I cannot help you here.

Answer (score 3):

Dont forget [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx) which supports pinning objects (and retrieving the address as an [IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx)). Pinning objects aren't exclusive to unsafe code (the fixed statement).